# Angular2 - How to import a custom component for my test project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, components, custom-component

I created a test component using Angular 2, and published it in npm. Now I'm trying to reuse this component in a Angular 2 project.

The component I created and published in npm is the zpt-input.

I try the following error when running npm start:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module './zpt-input'.`

I'm using the 6.4.0 version of Node.js

My **systemjs.config.js**:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'zpt-input':                  'node_modules/zpt-input'
  };

  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'zpt-input':                  { main: 'zpt-input.js', defaultJSExtensions: true}
  };
```

already I tried to import in many ways:

```
import { ZptInputComponent } from './zpt-input'; 
import { ZptInputComponent } from 'zpt-input';
```

My **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.4",

"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",

"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"zpt-input": "^0.0.5"
```

I need any more configuration? Thanks